# How to access the customised Azure AD login page in French Vs English from application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure and cloud based development so please pardon if my question seems obvious. My company is developing an application in C#.net that uses Azure AD for authentication. We want customized English and French versions of the login page.

What I did to generate the login code is:

1. Through Visual Studio created a new MVC application
2. Changed the authentication for application to "Work and School Accounts"
3. Finally entered the details for Web App name, App Service Plan, Resource Group, Region and Database server

This created the application with the code for authentication.

Azure does detect the language preferences in my browser and loads the English or French version accordingly. This won't work for our clients though. We want the application to be able to load different versions of login page. A way around this is to include the parameter lc=1036 (for locale fr-FR) in the login URL. My problem is that I don't know how to insert the parameter "lc=1036" in the login URL. How can I do this?

Thanks everyone for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem. This what got it done.

In the `startup.auth.cs` edited the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(` method and added the following:

```
 RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-CA")
                            context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("lc", "1036");

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
```

Hope this helps someone.